# How to run python in web browser, planning to develop one basic page using python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have installed python as well as I have installed pycharm IDE [without this i am unable to open and run] as well.

It is showing in output in console. i need to develop one basic project run on browser from my own for practice.

Comment: You might also want to look into Django

Answer (score 0):

you can run python online on **Google Colab**(it has an in-built GPU)

or you could install the **anaconda Python Distribution bundle**,to use their *Jupyter Notebook*

Also **Brython** which supports *python 3*

I hope I answered your question,if not let me know

Comment: I have tested all list, from my point of view. brython is the right choice for web application. Please tell me how to overcome tabs and space issue for coding.

Comment: In future we need to add bunch of coding, how to overcome in easy way! Most of the other programming language does not have these kind of problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can't run python directly in browser as browsers only support js. But it can be ran in terminal(if your are in linux) else install python in windows and type command

```
python3 somefile.py #in linux

somefile.py #works directly in linux
```

You can check this [run python scripts](https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/) in windows and terminal.

But if your requirement is to run python for a web application you can set it up on server as API or using gRPC documentation here [check this out](https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/)